# No domain in Facebook (Meta) Pixel ad, and event limit

Tags: facebook-ads-manager, tracking-pixel

When I start to make an ad in Facebook (Meta) ads with Pixel events, I see the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Note: I set up all e-commerce events via GTM, and the domain is verified.

What is the problem and how I can solve it?